# kendo multiselect refresh list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

i am try kendo multiselect tab remove when click on button and again this remove option in come to select. 
i have done this code
 
 Close Oranges

```
<script>
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
  tagTemplate: "<span class='mitesh12' entity_id ='${data.id}' path ='${data.name}' >" + '#: data.name #' + "</span>",
});
function closeOrange(e){
    $("span[entity_id='2']").parent().parent().remove();
}
</script>
```

this is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WfGA/19/) and i want like this [Like](http://jsfiddle.net/9WfGA/21/)

here i am try to remove **orange** tag and after remove this again i am able to select this **orange** 
help me out this
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not follow the same approach than your second link.

Define the HTML as:

```
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>
<button id="oranges" class="k-button">Close Oranges</button>
```

And this code for creating the multiselect:

```
var multi = $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
  tagTemplate: "<span class='mitesh12' entity_id ='${data.id}' path ='${data.name}' >" + '#: data.name #' + "</span>",
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

The button handler for removing the value is:

```
$("#oranges").on("click", function(e) {
    // List of values to remove (only the ones with id = 2)
    var subtract = [2];
    var values = multi.value().slice();
    values = $.grep(values, function(a) {
        return $.inArray(a, subtract) == -1;
    });
    // Filter out everything
    multi.dataSource.filter({});
    // Now add the remaining values.
    multi.value(values);
});
```

You can see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/9WfGA/23/